# Get a text from CHtmlEditView

Tags: mfc

I am using `CHtmlEditView` class for my edit control. I want to get text written in the edit control. `GetWindowText()` returns an empty string. Not sure its supported but not giving me any warning either. I tried `IHTMLDocument2` interface to get a text. I am getting a text but in html format (text written in `<body>`). So I am not sure how to get text only from CHtmlEditView control. I have gone through  list of APIs of CHtmlEditView and its base classes but I did not get anything there. Can any one know how to get a text from CHtmlEditView ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[IHTMLElement::innerText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh869989(v=vs.85).aspx)

> Sets or retrieves the text between the start and end tags of the
>   object.

Example:

```
CHtmlEditView html_edit;
// or CHtmlEditCtrl html_edit;
...

CString getPlainText()
{
    CComPtr<IHTMLDocument2> doc2;
    html_edit.GetDHtmlDocument(&doc2);

    CComPtr<IHTMLElement> element;
    doc2->get_body(&element);

    CComBSTR bstr;
    element->get_innerText(&bstr);
    CString text = bstr;
    return text;
}
```

Comment: `element->put_innerText(bstr)`

Comment: Thanks Barmak, I have tried that and it  solved my issue. Is there 'EN_CHANGE' like notification  for 'CHtmlEditView'. I am not able to get an notification when there is change in 'CHtmlEditView' text with 'EN_CHANGE'

Comment: You can't ask consecutive questions in comment section. If your question has been answered then check the green mark to accept it.